# Jenkins treats any non-zero exit code as error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is a concern as we have an executable which returns 2 as warning. We do not want to fail the Jenkins build pipeline just because of this. How can we modify the pipeline to accept an exit code 2, and prints out a reasonable warning message based on the exit code?

```
D:\Stage>c:\bin\mycommand
script returned exit code 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `sh` or `bat` in a Jenkins pipeline it will always fail the build (and throw an exception) for any non zero exit code - and that cannot be changed.
What you can do is use the `returnStatus` of the [sh step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) (or cmd) which will return the exit code of the script instead of failing the build, and then you can use something like:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Run Script') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def exitCode = sh script: 'mycommand', returnStatus: true
                    if (exitCode == 2) {
                        // do something
                    }
                    else if (exitCode){
                        // other non-zero exit codes
                    }
                    else {
                        // exit code 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only drawback of this approach is that `returnStatus` cannot be used together with `returnStdout`, so if you need to get the returned output you will need to get it in another way (write to file and then read it for example).

Comment: Clever `else if` implicit cast to boolean, but otherwise would recommend type casting the return with an `int` instead of general object `def`.